# Set PowerShell Azure SQL Connection String Parameter

Tags: powershell, variables, connection-string, azure-keyvault, azure-sql

I have an **Azure SQL database** in one resource group and a **key vault** in a separate resource group. Everything is already deployed but I'd like to assign the **connection string values of the sql db** to a variable and user it to **create a secret in my key vault resource**. I currently have this set as the connection string value:

**$dbsecretvalue = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Server=tcp:$sqlServerfqdn,1433;Initial Catalog=$database;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=$adminlogin;Password=$password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30" -AsPlainText -Force**

The problem is in key vault this **additional text** is being added to the secret value instead of just the server name:
Server=tcp:***@{FullyQualifiedDomainName***=servername.azure.net......

How do I go about removing the additional text so only the **FQDN** of my sql db is returned when I set the variable (ex: databaseserver.azure.net instead of @{FullyQualifiedDomainName=databaserver.azure.net)? I have very limited powershell experience so any help/advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to remove the partial string from the $sqlServerfqdn variable or are you trying to prevent the variable from getting the  ":@{FullyQualifiedDomainName" added in the first place? If the second option, could you please share how you are setting that variable.

Comment: Here's how I set the variable: $sqlserverfqdn = Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ServerName $sqlServer | Select FullyQualifiedDomainName. This returns a 'FullyQualifiedDomainName' header with the name of my db listed under it. I only want the name of the database returned. When I create the secret in my vault (see cmd above for how I create secret) '@{FullyQualifiedDomainName=' is also being added which isn't a valid connection string. I need '@{FullyQualifiedDomainName=' removed so only server name host name (fdqn) is listed/returned. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this. The simplest is going to be to break this up into two lines:

```
$server = Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ServerName $sqlServer
$sqlserverfqdn = $server.FullyQualifiedDomainName
$sqlserverfqdn
#output databaserver.azure.net
```

This command is fine, and in general Powershell will try to make the JSON into an object by default, but once in awhile piping into `ConvertFrom-Json` will get the data loaded into an object you can manipulate that way

If you need to clean a string, then the replace method will usually handle it:

```
$fqdn = '@{FullyQualifiedDomainName=databaserver.azure.net'
$sqlserverfqdn = $fqdn -replace "@{FullyQualifiedDomainName=",""
```

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you for the help!